# design editor is unavailable until next gradle sync

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Скачала с GitHub файл с кодом, пробовала запустить в Android Studio.

Ошибка с Gradle, пишет design editor is unavailable until next gradle sync.

Искала в гугле  ответ. Теперь пишет:failed to initialize editor.

Что делать? Может я файл не правильно загрузила?

Comment: File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Отформатируйте ошибки

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема: решена с помощью обновления Gradle на максимум,Kotlin и Android Studio. Проблема была вызвана тем, что я не учел. что коллега поднял зависимости на актуальные свежие уровни - а я всё в прошлом лепил в своей ветке.